# Dropdown in my CSS navigation not showing up in the right place

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, navigation, joomla2.5

I have created a CSS drop down menu for this Joomla site I am developing (not using a plugin) and for some reason the sub-menus are appearing on the left hand side of the navigation, regardless of where the parent item of that submenu happens to be.

http://digitaldemo.net/anova/

Here is the HTML for the menu as it appears on the site:

```
<div id="navbar">
<div id="nav">
<ul class="menu">
<li class="item-101 current active"><a href="/anova/" >Home</a></li>
<li class="item-107 deeper parent"><a href="/anova/index.php/about-the-book" >About The Book</a>
   <ul>
   <li class="item-118"><a href="/anova/index.php/about-the-book/contributors" >Contributors</a></li>
   <li class="item-119"><a href="/anova/index.php/about-the-book/reviews" >Reviews</a></li>   
   <li class="item-120"><a href="/anova/index.php/about-the-book/standards-and-stem" >Standards and STEM</a></li>
   <li class="item-137"><a href="#" >More Emphasis Conditions</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li class="item-108 deeper parent"><a href="/anova/index.php/what-s-in-the-book" >What's In The Book?</a>
   <ul>
   <li class="item-121"><a href="/anova/index.php/what-s-in-the-book/content-summary" >Content Summary</a></li>
   <li class="item-122"><a href="/anova/index.php/what-s-in-the-book/how-to-use-this-book" >How to Use This Book</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li class="item-109"><a href="/anova/index.php/buy-the-book" >Buy The Book</a></li>
<li class="item-110 deeper parent"><a href="/anova/index.php/what-is-the-rip" >What is the RIP®?</a>
   <ul>
   <li class="item-138"><a href="/anova/index.php/what-is-the-rip/uniqueness-philosophy" >Uniqueness &amp; Philosophy</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li class="item-111"><a href="/anova/index.php/contact-us" >Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
#nav {
    width:960px ;
    margin:auto ;
    text-align:center ;
}

#nav ul.menu {
  margin-left:0 ;
  padding-left:0 ;
  margin-top:-5px ;
  list-style-type:none ;
  text-align:center ;
  height:59px ;
}

#nav ul.menu li {
  display:inline ;
  background:transparent ;
  margin-left:40px ;
}

#nav .menu li a {
  display:inline-block ;
  height:59px ;
  font-size:18px ;
  color:#e8e8e8 ;
  border-top:5px solid #3157a7 ;
  line-height:54px ;
  position:relative ;
}

#nav .menu li a:hover, #nav .menu li.current a {
  background:url("../images/menu-arrow.png") no-repeat center ;
  border-top:5px solid #607cbc ;
  z-index:9999 ;
  position:relative ;
}


#nav .menu li:first-child {
  margin-left:0px !important ;
}

    .menu li ul { position:absolute ;
    top:54px ;
    width:220px ;
    float:none ;
    padding-left:0px ;
    background:#4d4d4d ;
    overflow:visible ;
    z-index:5 ;
    text-align:left ;
    margin-left:0px ;
    }

    .menu li li { display:none !important ;
    padding:0 ;
    margin:0 !important ;
    background:#4d4d4d ;
    border-left:none ;
    border-top:1px solid #616161 ;
    }

    .menu li li:first-child {
  border-top:0px !important ;
  }

    .menu li.current li a {
  background-image:none !important ;
}

    .menu li li a   { display:block ;
    background:#4d4d4d ; ;
    padding:5px 10px !important ;
    font-size:17px !important ;
    height:25px !important ;
    line-height:25px !important ;
    text-transform:none ;
    position:relative ;
    border-top:0px !important ;
    top:0px ;
    }

    .menu li li:first-child a    { border-top:none }

    .menu li li a:hover    { background:#808080 ;
    background-image:none !important ;
    }

    .menu li:hover li { float: none; display:block !important ; clear: both; }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Cynthia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the dropdowns relative to the parent list item, so you would want to add something like this:

```
#nav ul.menu li {
    position:relative;
}
```

After doing that, it looks like then you will have to fix the position on the dropdown unordered lists as well as probably just readjust spacing and things, but I'm betting that you can handle that.

Comment: That fixes it in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE the problem still persists.

Comment: Hmmm... Yes. This won't work consistently unless the parent `li` is a block not inline. You can either use `display:inline-block` as a quick fix with some poor early IE issues, or you would want to float the `li` items to the left, which will get them inline but as block level elements. This will screw up your centering, so you may want to look at this guide for an excellent guide on this: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/centered-dropdown-menus